# Encode \x{57fc}\x{7389}\x{770c} as Japanese Text

Tags: java, perl, encode

I have the following response from my back-end servers (Java):

```
\x{57fc}\x{7389}\x{770c}
```

When I try to encode in Perl, I get this:

```
JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode($text);
output: å¼çç
```

It should be:

```
埼玉県
```

What method can I use in Perl to display this Japanese text correctly? The page encoding is correct as other Japanese text shows up properly, it's just this piece of code that's returned by Java that is odd.

Comment: Are those kanji characters supported in UTF-8?

Comment: If you want the output to be `三重県`, shouldn't the response from the back-end servers be `\x{4e09}\x{91cd}\x{770c}`? With the current response, you would get the characters `埼玉県` instead.

Comment: Try a hexdump of the output, it may be a terminal issue

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, UTF-8 supports the entire Unicode character set.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of of `{ local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($text, JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode($text))); }`

Comment: @Lonenebula Without knowing how to encode them, I wasn't sure which ones it was. How did you translate it?

Comment: I wrote this Java program: `System.out.println("\u57fc\u7389\u770c");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was pretty simple. The text is already utf8 when it looks like that. So simply removing the utf8 option solved the issue.

```
JSON::XS->new->encode($text);
```